# Ubuntu: gedit' not found, but can be installed with

Tags: ubuntu, gedit, wsl-2

I am trying to install Valgrind on my windows 10. I am using Ubuntu and was able to install valgrind smoothly. However, when trying to set the path using the command: `gedit .bashrc` I am getting the error:

```
Command 'gedit' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gedit
```

So I did install gedit and reload the command window and run this again: `gedit .bashrc` but I keep getting the same error. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these, should fix the issue

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit

Comment: now I get the following: `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:9202): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:48:48.962: cannot open display:`

Comment: I have cygwinX installed somewhere but how can I use it to fix this error

Comment: You should post that as another question. I don't have specific knowledge of cygwinX. But i found this on ask ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121696/gedit76-gtk-warning

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful.